# Save variable on computer

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

For my first project in Python I am trying to create a Discord bot. My project is on a GitHub repo on public. Obviously I don't want my private bot key be accessible by anyone. I was wondering if there is a way for me to declare a variable on my local disk where I can put my key and just access it from my project. This way, anyone can consult my repo without having access to my key.

Thanks

Comment: There's two commonly used options... Environment variables or  a `token.json` file.

Comment: To add to the previous comment, please also make sure to create a `.gitignore` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the key to some form of persistent memory. For this you can simply save a file on your hard drive and read it when your script starts.

```
def main():
    bot_key = ''
    with open('./discord_key.txt', 'r') as f: bot_key = f.read()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: but you have to make sure that you update the gitgnore file